# Call to a member function addvoter() on null

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, postman

On Laravel 5.4.1 I'm always getting this error when using ajax

> FatalThrowableError in avController.php line 53: Call to a member function addvoter() on null

but it seems to work perfectly without ajax. I think the problem starts from  `$request->user()->addvoter()->save($voter);` which is my line 53 but I don't understand it;

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')){ 
           $voter = new voter();
           $voter->FirstName = $request->fname;
           $voter->LastName= $request->lname;
           $voter->Email = $request->email;
           $voter->PhoneNumber = $request->phone;
           $voter->Gender = $request->optradio;
           $voter->StudentID = $request->sID;
           $voter->Level = $request->level;
           $voter->Course = $request->course;
           $voter->Stream = $request->stream;
           $voter->Nationality = $request->nat;
           $voter->ProfileImg = $request->image;     

           $request->user()->addvoter()->save($voter);

          $response = array(
               'fname' => $request->fname,
               'lname' => $request->lname, 
               'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
           );
             return response()->json($response);
       }
       return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
}
```

my user model

```
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function addcandidate(){
    return $this->hasMany('elpebi\addcandidate');
} 
 public function addstcandidate(){
    return $this->hasMany('elpebi\stcandidate');
}
public function addvoter(){
    return $this->hasMany('elpebi\voter');
}
public function newelection(){
    return $this->hasMany('elpebi\election');
}
```

my voter model

```
protected $fillable = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 
                       'Gender', 'StudentID', 'Level', 'Course',       
                       'Stream', 'Nationality', 'ProfileImg' ];
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('elpebi\User');
}
```

Comment: I guess your "user" is not set because you are using an ajax call without CSRF protection? In any case, the problem seems to be related with the fact that the user is null.

Answer (score 0):

If your user is logged in, I think you can do this:

```
auth()->user()->addvoter()->save($voter);
```